# variables dinamicas desde archivo .json PHP

Tags: php, json, variables

Hola tengo este archivo json con el siguiente formato.

json con la estrutura

```
 {
    "Install": "Instalacion",
    "Idioma": {
        "lang": "es",
        "name": "Español",
        "languajes": "Idiomas",
        "welcome": "Bienvenido"
    }
}
```

tengo este codigo php para sacar las variables dimanicas

```
$Json         = ControllerAdminLenguajes::ctrJsons();
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                    new RecursiveArrayIterator($Json),
                    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
                );
foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        ${$key} = $Json[$key];
    }else {
        ${$key} = $val;
    }
}
```

Todo esto me funciona muy bien y me crea las variables dinamicamente de esta forma.

```
$Install           = 'Instalacion';
$Idioma['lang']    = 'es';
$Idioma['welcome'] = 'Bienvenido';
```

El problema que tengo es cuando quiero dar este formato al .json

```
 {
    "Install": "Instalacion",
    "Idioma": {
        "lang": "es",
        "name": "Español",
        "languajes": "Idiomas",
        "welcome": "Bienvenido"
    },
    "System":{
        "opcion": "opcion",
        "config": {
            "a": "a"
        }
    }
}
```

me dice Warning: Undefined array key "config", lo que quiero hacer es algo como

```
$System['opcion'] = 'opcion';
$System['config']['a'] = 'a'; no se si my logica estaria corecta...
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Voy a utilizar el JSON dentro del código de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

$Json = <<<JSON
{
    "Install": "Instalacion",
    "Idioma": {
        "lang": "es",
        "name": "Español",
        "languajes": "Idiomas",
        "welcome": "Bienvenido"
    },
    "System":{
        "opcion": "opcion",
        "config": {
            "a": "a"
        }
    }
}
JSON;

$json_decoded = json_decode($Json, TRUE);

$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                    new RecursiveArrayIterator($json_decoded),
                    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
                
foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        ${$key} = $json_decoded[$key];
    }else {
        ${$key} = $val;
    }
}
```

Si haces un:

`var_dump(get_defined_vars());`

para ver las variables definidas, omitiendo las globales y entre otras tendrás las creadas dinámicamente:

```
  ["Install"]=>
  string(11) "Instalacion"
  ["Idioma"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["lang"]=>
    string(2) "es"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Español"
    ["languajes"]=>
    string(7) "Idiomas"
    ["welcome"]=>
    string(10) "Bienvenido"
  }
  ["lang"]=>
  string(2) "es"
  ["name"]=>
  string(8) "Español"
  ["languajes"]=>
  string(7) "Idiomas"
  ["welcome"]=>
  string(10) "Bienvenido"
  ["System"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["opcion"]=>
    string(6) "opcion"
    ["config"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["a"]=>
      string(1) "a"
    }
  }
  ["opcion"]=>
  string(6) "opcion"
  ["config"]=>
  NULL
  ["a"]=>
  string(1) "a"
```

Por lo qué, haciendo lo siguiente:

```
var_dump($System['config']['a']);
```

Va a imprimir el contenido correctamente:

```
string(1) "a"
```

Revisa como carga el JSON o intenta usar `get_defined_vars` para ver las variables definidas.

Comment: me da como respuesta Notice: Undefined index: config

Comment: ¿Estás usando tu JSON que recibes de X manera o el JSON de prueba que metí “a mano”?

Comment: use el codigo tuyo

Comment: use tu codigo de prueba y me dice Notice: Undefined index: config in C:\xampp\htdocs\array\prueba_json.php on line 30

Comment: ya pude resolver lo con solamente cambiar is_array por is_object